# Is there a way to create a search function in Excel that has 3-4 variable as inputs and returns only a single output?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a project capital estimating tool on excel. In the data that I have I need at least 3 variables to identify a specific piece of equipment that a project might need. For example The name of a fitting, its size, and the fluid that flows through it and this would return the unit cost price (which I already have in my database). Just need it to be in a tidy lookup function. Thank you

Comment: Would need to see an example of the DB to see what you were looking for. If you have tried anything yet, please show a copy of it. Off the top of my head, an INDEX / MATCH function would work.

Comment: A normal row would be

Item Type | Datasheet | Service | Location | Sub-location | Manufacturer | Supplier | Cost Price | Quote # | Quote Date| 

For Example

| Ball | HDN - 123| Lix | Trunkline | N/A | 123fittings | 123fittings | 737 | Q1234 | 1/1/06 |

Comment: I only really need the, Item Type, Datasheet, Service, Supplier to identify the correct part though

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  I suggest you familiarize yourself with how this site works, though. Start by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I started making a column and gave each piece of equipment a unique identifier and just used the lookup function.

Comment: You can treat a block of cells in excel as a sql database using ADO, you could then write a sql query to return the data. Examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817911/vba-adodb-select-query-using-the-excel-sheet-of-the-same-workbook-as-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your data, both search criteria & database in excel you can use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim strType As String, Datasheet As String, Service As String, Supplier As String, SearchString As String
    Dim i As Long, Lastrow As Long
    Dim wsCriteria As Worksheet, wsDatabase As Worksheet

    Set wsCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Criteria")
    Set wsDatabase = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Criteria")

        strType = .Range("B2").Value
        Datasheet = .Range("B3").Value
        Service = .Range("B4").Value
        Supplier = .Range("B5").Value

        SearchString = strType & "_" & Datasheet & "_" & Service & "_" & Supplier

    End With

    Lastrow = wsDatabase.Cells(wsDatabase.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To Lastrow

            If wsDatabase.Range("A" & i).Value & "_" & wsDatabase.Range("B" & i).Value & "_" & wsDatabase.Range("C" & i).Value & "_" & wsDatabase.Range("G" & i).Value = SearchString Then
                wsCriteria.Range("A7:J7").Clear
                wsCriteria.Range("A7").Value = wsDatabase.Range("A" & i).Value
                wsCriteria.Range("B7").Value = wsDatabase.Range("B" & i).Value
                wsCriteria.Range("C7").Value = wsDatabase.Range("C" & i).Value
                wsCriteria.Range("D7").Value = wsDatabase.Range("D" & i).Value
                wsCriteria.Range("E7").Value = wsDatabase.Range("E" & i).Value
                wsCriteria.Range("F7").Value = wsDatabase.Range("F" & i).Value
                wsCriteria.Range("G7").Value = wsDatabase.Range("G" & i).Value
                wsCriteria.Range("H7").Value = wsDatabase.Range("H" & i).Value
                wsCriteria.Range("I7").Value = wsDatabase.Range("I" & i).Value
                wsCriteria.Range("J7").Value = wsDatabase.Range("J" & i).Value
                Exit For
            End If

        Next i

End Sub
```

Sheet Named "Criteria" before and after:

[image]

[image]

Sheet Named "Database":

[image]